# why threejs change my canvas size 2x?

Tags: three.js

```
#designer {
        height: 480px;
        width: 640px;
    }
var designer = document.getElementById('designer');

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true,preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(designer.clientWidth, designer.clientHeight);
    designer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

browser showes the html code like below:

```
 <canvas width="1280" height="960" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></canvas>
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In three.js r.70, when you call the method

```
renderer.setSize( width, height );
```

the `renderer.domElement` logical canvas dimensions are scaled by the `pixelRatio` you previously set when you called

```
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ).
```

The `canvas.style` dimensions are, unchanged.

This is different behavior than in prior versions of the three.js library.

three.js r.70